# How can I update MySQL table row's when 'BEFORE UPDATE' trigger is firing?

Tags: mysql, triggers

*I created a table*

Databases Name - **mytrigger;**
Table name - **employee_audit**

```
use mytrigger;
create table employee_audit(
     id int auto_increment primary key,
     employeeNumber int not null,
     lastName varchar(50) not null,
     changee datetime default null,
     action varchar(50) default null
    );
```

After that, I created one update trigger

My trigger name is

**before_employees_update**

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger before_employees_update
before update on employee_audit
for each row
begin
insert into employee_audit
set action ='update',
employeeNumber = OLD.employeeNumber,
lastName = OLD.lastName,
changee = now();
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

After that, I inserted values in table using this command ->

```
insert into employee_audit values(1,112,'prakash','2015-11-12 15:36:20' ,' ');
```

> After that, I want to update my table row where id =1

```
update employee_audit set lastName = 'Sharma' where employeeNumber =112;
```

But it is not executed give an error

> ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'employee_audit' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger.

When I searched on Google I found a lot of Question with the same error. But not able to fix my problem. what is the reason I'm not able to update my row?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you can't do an update on a table which caused that trigger to fire.  Perhaps you can rethink your logic to avoid this need.

Comment: Tell us more about how you ended up with this design and maybe someone can give you a workaround.

Comment: @Tim I'm new in MySQL trigger I am following this tutorial
 http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

Comment: Re-read my first comment.  MySQL doesn't allow recursive triggers, so what you are trying to do here won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i suggest,you can create one `log table` like `employee_audit_LOG` .

And on every insert or update in main table you can make new entry in this table or update existing record.

Also you can add `updated_timestamp column` to that `LOG` table which maintain when did specific record get updated.

Comment: Okay, so I need to create one more table to update this?

Comment: @VedPrakash Yes,according to i had understand your requirements for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The error itself tells you the answer. This is because, you can't use the same table on which trigger is being executed. You need to store your audit logs into some different table.

Comment: Could you please help me how to store audit logs into some different table.

Comment: @VedPrakash Its very simple. create table 'employee_audit_log' same as 'employee_audit' and use 'insert into employee_audit_log' from trigger.